# Class objects contains both _<var> and <var> attributes when using property decorator

Tags: python, oop, properties, python-decorators, python-class

I have the following class. I  want to keep _my_var = None if the user does not provide a value for that. They can use the setter to set it, where I enforce some validation

```
class A:
  _my_var = None

  @property
  def my_var(self):
      return self._my_var
   
  @property.setter
  def my_var(self, value)
      # Some validation
      return._my_var = value
```

I am creating an object in the following code

`x = A()`

When I look at the attributes x has

```
 _my_var: None
 my_var: None
```

When I set `x._myvar = 10` both `my_var` and `_my_var` attributes are set to 10. I have a confusion about this. IS _my_var  a field and my_var is a function? How can keep only _my_var as the attribute while enforcing the setter to set it?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? The instance x *doesn't* have an attribute my_var - it has a property. How do you look at the attributes?

Comment: i used dir(x) to inspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you made `my_var` a property, but in the function it returns `self._my_var`, so if you change the `self._my_var` to `10`, and then you call the `my_var` function again, it would return the modified `self._my_var` value.

Setting the `my_var` function to a `@property` could confuse you, it acts like it's just attribute of the class, but it's actually a function, just it is called without parenthesis. If you make it a regular function without `@property` like:

```
    def my_var(self):
        return self._my_var
```

Then it would be more obvious that it's a function because you would call it like:

```
x._myvar = 10
print(x.my_var())
```

Would give:

```
10
```

This would make it more obvious.

To make it not change according to `_my_var`, change the function to an variable, so instead of:

```
    def my_var(self):
        return self._my_var
```

Make it:

```
    self.my_var = int(self._my_var)
```

Comment: Is this the correct way to add a setter for a private attribute? is the naming conversion correct. Var name: _my_var, Property setter name: my_var()?

Comment: @Malintha sure. This is typical

Comment: @Malintha Yes, added more explanation about this.